# varchar column size wrong lost data

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database, it was setup with the wrong size column, I used varchar(200), the column was meant to hold 50 words in a survey website. I have collected 800 surveys and half of them are cut off. Is there any way of getting the data back?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think there's any solution for you.

Comment: means all column hold 50 character or less ? or some column have more then 50 chars ??